# cakephp error: unexpected '(', expecting ')', is my syntax wrong?

Tags: syntax, cakephp-2.0

Do you see any syntax errors here?

```
'Coupon'=>array(
            'fields'=>array(
                'promo_code','desc'
            ),
            'conditions'=>array(
                        'OR'=>array(
                            'expires' =>0,
                            'Coupon.end_date >'=>date('Y-m-d')
                        )
            )
        ),
```

This is part of my 'contain' array in my controller code.  When I remove this snippet from my code, cake works great (only I need this part!).  Am posting the entire statement below.  Help?

```
public $paginate = array(
    'Location'=>array(
        'joins' => array(
             array( 
                'table' => 'locations_tags', 
                'alias' => 'LocationsTag', 
                'type' => 'inner',
                'conditions'=> array( 
                'LocationsTag.location_id = Location.id'
                )
            )
        ),
        'limit'=>9,
        'contain'=>array(
        'Course'=>array(
            'fields'=>array(
                'specials', 'contact','desc'
                ),
            'conditions'=>array('Course.active'=>1)
            ),
        'Charter'=>array(
            'fields'=>array(
                'book','specials', 'contact','desc'
                ),
            'conditions'=>array('Charter.active'=>1)
            ),
        'Restaurant'=>array(
            'fields'=>array(
                'menu','wine_list','specials', 'contact','desc'
                ),
            'conditions'=>array('Restaurant.active'=>1)
            ),
        'Nightclub'=>array(
            'fields'=>array(
                'menu','schedule','specials', 'contact','desc'
                ),
            'conditions'=>array('Nightclub.active'=>1)
            ),
        'Store'=>array(
            'fields'=>array(
                'catalog','specials', 'contact','desc'
                ),
            'conditions'=>array('Store.active'=>1)
            ),
        'Coupon'=>array(
            'fields'=>array(
                'promo_code','desc'
            ),
            'conditions'=>array(
                        'OR'=>array(
                            'expires' =>0,
                            'Coupon.end_date >'=>date('Y-m-d')
                        )
            )
        ),
        'Image',
        'Tag'=>array(
            'fields'=>array(
                'seo_tag'
            )
            )
        )
    )
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
        'Coupon.end_date >'=>date('Y-m-d')
```

You can't assign calculated values (e.g., calling functions) in class property declarations. They have to be constant values.

For a calculated value, you'd have to assign that in the constructor or something.

From [the docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php):

> This declaration may include an initialization, but this initialization must be a constant value--that is, it must be able to be evaluated at compile time and must not depend on run-time information in order to be evaluated.